# Nodemailer multiple recipients

Tags: javascript, express, reactjs, nodemailer

I'm using Nodemailer with mailgun to send emails to an array of users. I'm generating the HTML to send for the email with React. I want to pass in the current "to" in my emails array to the React component so I can use it within the React component.

I need to know which user I'm dealing with before the callback since I need it to generate the HTML

**NODE**

```
const emails = ['email1@gmail.com', 'email2@gmail.com'];

nodemailerMailgun.sendMail({
  from: 'myemail@example.com',
  to: emails,
  subject: 'Event Invitation',

  // how can i pass in the current "to" from my emails array into my react component below?
  html: renderToString(<InvitationEmail from="myemail@example.com" to="WHAT HERE" eventId={eventId} />)
})
```

**REACT**

```
const InvitationEmail = React.createClass({
  getDefaultProps() {
    return {
      from: '',
      to: ''
    }
  },
  render() {
    let { to, from } = this.props

     return (
       <div style={{ 'textAlign': 'center' }} className="InvitationEmail">
         <h1>Yo {to}, You've Been Invited!</h1>
       </div>
     )
 }
})
```

Comment: The component renders an individual email, right? If that's true, do you need to pass `emails` to the component? Why not loop over `emails`, pass the current email to the component (not the list of all emails), and call `sendMail` with the rendered html?

Comment: I guess I could call sendMail multiple times for every email, but it seems silly since they support sending multiple emails via an array.

Comment: It seems that what they support is not sending *multiple emails* at once but a *single email to multiple recipients* at once. To send multiple emails, the `html` attribute cannot be a string, it has to be a function, so that you can parametrize the `to` prop. You can catenate all of the emails by looping over  emails inside the component, but then you'll send all email bodies to individual recipients. (Play around with the API some more, I'm confident they have thought about this task before.)

Comment: That distinction makes a ton of sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To send the mail to multiple users you have to place them in a data type String, separated by commas, an example

```
const arrayUsersMail = ['emailOne@example.com', 'emailTwo@example.com', 'emailThree@example.com', 'emailFour@example.com' ]

const stringUsersMail = arrayUsersMail.join(', ')

nodemailerMailgun.sendMail({
from: 'myemail@example.com',
to: stringUsersMail,
subject: 'Event Invitation',
html: renderToString(<InvitationEmail from="myemail@example.com" to="WHAT HERE" eventId={eventId} />)
```

})

Answer (score 1):

While [@Potier97's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67349165/1762556) is correct, I strongly recommend you instead send each recipient a separate e-mail (aka loop through your list of recipients and call `sendMail` for each). This is because sending an e-mail to multiple recipients means each recipient get the exact same e-mail. They can also see all the other recipients and can Reply to all. I don't know about your specific use case but it's very unlikely that you actually want to do this

```js
const emails = ['email1@gmail.com', 'email2@gmail.com'];

for (const email of emails) {
  nodemailerMailgun.sendMail({
    from: 'myemail@example.com',
    to: email,
    subject: 'Event Invitation',
    html: renderToString(<InvitationEmail from="myemail@example.com" to={email} eventId={eventId} />)
  })

}
```